# glimpse is undefined in IE9

Tags: glimpse

I have installed Glimpse for ASP.NET MVC3 using the nuget package manager. I have followed the instructions maintained using the following [link](http://getglimpse.com/Version/Install/?Glimpse=1.0.1)

But when I tried to run the application using the IE9 browser I am getting an error : `glimpse` is undefined.

Please find the screen shot as mentioned below for error details:
[image: Webpage Error: 'glimpse' is undefined]

Comment: Have you gone to your application path's `glimpse.axd` (e.g. `http://myapplication.com/glimpse.axd`) and turned Glimpse on?

Comment: This issue is now being tracked on the [Glimpse GitHub Issue Tracker](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/280). Please follow the conversation there and I will try to update this SQ question with the result.

Comment: We have patched this issue. The fix will be available in the release after Glimpse 1.0.1.